# how have android notifications when an app is closed

Tags: java, android, notifications

I want to send notifications to the user, even if my app is closed. I heard about GCM but I don't think it's the best solution for me. I also tried to use Service, but it doesn't seem to work either. Does somebody have a idea on how can I perform that?

```
public class notificationService extends Service {
Timer timer;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(), 10*1000);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onCreate();

}


}




class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icone)
                        .setContentTitle("My notification")
                        .setContentText("Hello World!");
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Acceuil.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Acceuil.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Edit: i'm talking about this kind of notifications
[image]

Comment: "i want to send notification to android user even if my app is closed" -- what does "notification" mean here? Do you mean display a `Notification` on the status bar, the way your code is set up? If so, under what conditions do you want to display it "even if [your] app is closed"?

Comment: notifications send by my c++ server or daily notifications

Comment: If you want to send notifications out of your server, GCM a good way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCM can be tricky, but it is the Google recommended way of doing things. What I did was to follow these pages step by step and it worked for me, pretty quick to get up and running:

- [Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html)
- [Implementing GCM Client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) ("Running The Sample" below the page is great to start quickly)
- [Implementing GCM Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html)

#### Send via C++ Server

As mentioned, you have a C++ server, that you want to send notifications on. That is a little trickier, but doable. Here's what you need:

- OpenSSL BIO (So you can connect to the GCM HTTP Server via HTTPS)

  - [Secure programming with the OpenSSL API](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openssl/index.html) - Great guide by IBM
- Understanding how to "speak" HTTP via sockets (You need to POST)

  - http://coding.debuntu.org/c-linux-socket-programming-tcp-simple-http-client
  - Sample code below:

#### POSTing via OpenSSL BIO

```
// Request
stringstream ss;
string endline = "\r\n";

ss << "POST /gcm/send HTTP/1.0" << endline;
ss << "Host: android.googleapis.com" << endline;
ss << "Accept: */*" << endline;
ss << "Authorization: key=" << mKey << endline;
ss << "Content-Type: application/json" << endline;
ss << "Content-Length: " << ssbody.str().size() << endline;
ss << endline;
ss << ssbody.str();

syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "%s", ss.str().c_str());

int bioResult = 0;
do {
    bioResult = BIO_write(mBio, ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().length());
    if (bioResult <= 0) {
        this->restart();
    }
} while (bioResult <= 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a message using the onStop() or onPause() methods, depending on what you want to do.

For example, you can verify if you want to send a notification only if your app is running in background, or really when the user closes the app. To understand better about these two methods, I recommend you to see the specifications here: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I don't want to send a notification directly at the close of the app but few hours after

Answer (score 0):

if u used GCM registarar for register device. U have an device id. If your app still installed  on the phone. U can send notification when app is closed

Comment: The problem will be my c++ server and the integration of the GCM. I don't think google have made a c++ API to acces to GCM. Can I send notifications through GCM manually ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a push style of notification, I would recommend using Amazon's push notification service. It also includes sample code to get you started .

If you don't want a push style and rather just have a polling type (clients periodically check a server for messages ) you can use a service that periodically sends communication to a server, and if a certain response is received you can create a local notification. To do this the service should start on boot to ensure if a user restarts their phone , and hasn't opened your app, notifications can still come in.

Answer (score 0):

> notifications send by my c++ server

Use GCM to deliver the messages to the particular devices that need them. Your code on the device can then do what it wants.

> or daily notifications

Use `AlarmManager` to schedule points in time when your code should get control, and then do whatever is needed at those points.

Comment: I can't use GCM because i will be forced to change a lot of my c++ server code and i don't know if the GCM API for c++ exist and moreover I will not have anymore a direct connexion between my server and the client but i will forced to pass trough google's server

Comment: @DanSnow: "i don't know if the GCM API for c++ exist" -- it uses HTTP or XMPP. "I will not have anymore a direct connexion between my server and the client but i will forced to pass trough google's server" -- correct. However, maintaining your own long-lived socket connection to some server will be difficult to write in a reliable fashion and will consume more power and RAM on the device.